# StackOverFlowError Spark toDF() Reason

Tags: pyspark, stack-overflow

guys, I am beginner at Spark. I have large data in rdd. While converting rdd to DataFrame, I have error "StackOverFlowError".
I found solution [java.lang.StackOverFlowError when converting an RDD to a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58754635/java-lang-stackoverflowerror-when-converting-an-rdd-to-a-dataframe), but I don't understand the reason.

Could anyone explain what is the reason of the error?

Thanks!